# Blender 2.9 viewport overlays - show everything but verts, edges and faces in edit mode

Tags: 3d-view

To turn off everything but the vertices, edges and faces, we must disable everything in viewport overlays and leave itself simply on. Then, we need to turn the settings back on we have to sort of remember what the defaults settings were.

Is there a way to turn off the overlay, but the neccessary overlay of the specific modes?

[image]

Comment: Maybe Workspaces can achieve what you want. You can add a workspace using the + icon on the top ribbon, and customize it as you wish, it won't affect the other ones. Then when you want to go back to the previous state, select the original 3D workspace

Comment: This makes sense! Preparing custom workspaces allows easy transitions for such cases. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workspaces can achieve that behaviourn, as I don't think there is a built-in way for "remembering" overlay settings.

You can add a workspace using the + icon on the right of the top ribbon, and customize it as you wish, it won't affect the other ones.

Then when you want to go back to the previous state, select the original 3D Workspace.

Note that you can append workspaces from other files if you want to retrieve a particular setup from another project.

You can also change the layout in a new file and save it as the new default if you wish. Go to File > Defaults > Save Startup File.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This tip was very helpful.